# Formula for Next FollowUp Date depends on Last FollowUp Date

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields

[image]

When i set date in Last FollowUp date, in Next FollowUp date needs to generate automate date.

If in Last FollowUp date is monday  in Next FollowUp date needs to generate next Wednesday

If in Last FollowUp date is Wednesday in Next FollowUp date needs to generate next Friday.

If in Last FollowUp date is Friday in Next FollowUp date needs to generate next Monday.

Comment: What about the other days of the week?

Comment: Need just for this 3 for now...

Answer (score 1):

The formula you need is (Case 1 is Monday, Case 3 is Wednesday, Case 5 is Friday):

```
CASE(
  MOD(YourDate - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  1, DATE( YEAR( YourDate ), MONTH( YourDate  ), DAY( YourDate ) + 2 ),
  3, DATE( YEAR( YourDate ), MONTH( YourDate  ), DAY( YourDate ) + 2 ),
  5, DATE( YEAR( YourDate ), MONTH( YourDate  ), DAY( YourDate ) + 3 ), 
  YourDate
)
```